# Is webapp folder required in projects configured using java-config

Tags: spring-mvc, web.xml, servlet-3.0, spring-java-config

Typical Spring MVC Application structure as follows:

- src/main/java
- src/main/resources
- src/main/webapp
- src/test/java

webapp contains the web-inf folder and configuration files such as web.xml, dispatcher-servlet.xml.

Servlet 3.0 replaces xml configurations with java config. For example, instead web.xml, configuration can be done using java class extending AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.

If there is no html/js content needed and it is meant to be used as only a Restful service, do we need the webapp folder ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes , You can remove the webapps folder from your project still your project  will works fine.

If you want to develop restful application you can use **apache cxf** or **jersey** framework.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Now I am more curious, why choose apache cxf over spring mvc ? I only want to build json based Restul service. thus I thought spring mvc may be sufficient.

Comment: Its a matter of preference.Spring mvc is for developing web application which includes view/html pages  also we can send the data in json/xml format.Using jersey also you can send data in json /xml format ,its an implementation of Jax-rs specification.